# Jackson how to convert array of objects to flat properties in class depends on value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following `json` object came from remote service:

```
{
  "accumulators": [
    {
      "balance": "100",
      "name": "SMS",
      "units": "International SMS"
    },
    {
      "balance": "100",
      "name": "VOICE",
      "units": "minutes"
    },
    {
      "balance": "50",
      "name": "MMS",
      "units": "MMS"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wand to convert map it to the following class depends on the value of object inside that array, so if it is `"name": "MMS"` then the value must be set to the value of `AccumulatorDTO MMS;`:

```
public class BaseDTO {
    private AccumulatorDTO messages;
    private AccumulatorDTO minutes;
    private AccumulatorDTO MMS;

    // setters and geters
}

public class AccumulatorDTO {
    private int balance;
    private String name;
    private String units;

    // setters and geters
}
```

Any Idea how to do that using Jackson annotation or custom deserializer?

I can do something like:

```
AccumulatorDTO[] accumulators = (new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(response.asJson().get("accumulators"), AccumulatorDTO[].class);
```

Then make iteration over the array and set each property, but really hard to my project structure, I'm looking fo really better solution for a generic purpose (using 1 method for all remote servers, and the deserialization better to be inside DTO somehow, I'm doing some wrapping layer between frontend and backend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using reflection and name the `BaseDTO` fields according to the `name` field in the JSON. Using a `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor fulfils the requirement of *"deserialization better to be inside DTO somehow"*. E.g.

```
class BaseDTO {
    private AccumulatorDTO sms;
    private AccumulatorDTO voice;
    private AccumulatorDTO mms;

    @JsonCreator
    public BaseDTO(@JsonProperty("accumulators") final AccumulatorDTO[] accumulators) {
        for (AccumulatorDTO accumulator : accumulators) {
            String fieldName = accumulator.getName().toLowerCase();
            try {
                Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                field.set(this, accumulator);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
BaseDTO accumulators = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.asJson(), BaseDTO.class);
```

This will initialise the BaseDTO fields according to the array elements and their name. It will let a field be null if it can't match it to an array element and exceptions are thrown.

Jackson doesn't have an annotation to do what you want AFAIK.

Comment: Your answer helped me and looks clean, thanks. btw, look at my answer, edited version of your answer, if you suggest something let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided from @Manos Nikolaidis helped me so much to code my real answer, his answer is good to start, in my cause some of the values contains a spaces or just a non-standard, so I do create a map to map between fields on JSON and the class:

```
@JsonCreator
public AccountDTO(@JsonProperty("accumulators") final AccumulatorDTO[] accumulators) {
    HashMap<String, String> accumulatorsMap = new HashMap<>();
    // key is value from JSON, value is field name of class
    accumulatorsMap.put("intl sms", "internationalSMS");
    accumulatorsMap.put("voice", "minutes");
    accumulatorsMap.put("mms", "MMS");
    accumulatorsMap.put("voicemessage", "voiceMessages");
    accumulatorsMap.put("message", "messages");

    for (AccumulatorDTO accumulator : accumulators) {
        String fieldName = accumulator.getName().toLowerCase();
        try {
            Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(accumulatorsMap.get(fieldName));
            field.set(this, accumulator);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this Jackson custom deserializer for your BaseDTO class that satisfies your requirement. It looks for the "balance" property and when it found it knows that the following are "name" and "units" so it takes them. Then it switchs on the "name" property and it sets the current AccumulatorDTO to the right field of the BaseDTO class.

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BaseDTO>{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CustomDeserializer(Class<BaseDTO> t) {
    super(t);
}

@Override
public BaseDTO deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc)
                                            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    BaseDTO bd = new BaseDTO();
    JsonToken currentToken = null;
    while ((currentToken = jp.nextValue()) != null) {
        if (jp.getCurrentName() != null && jp.getCurrentName().equals("balance")) 
        {
            System.out.println(jp.getCurrentName());
            AccumulatorDTO adto = new AccumulatorDTO();
            adto.setBalance(Integer.parseInt(jp.getValueAsString()));
            currentToken = jp.nextValue();
            adto.setName(jp.getValueAsString());
            currentToken = jp.nextValue();
            adto.setUnits(jp.getValueAsString());
            switch (adto.getName().toLowerCase())
            {
                case "sms":
                    bd.setMessages(adto);
                    break;
                case "voice":
                    bd.setMinutes(adto);
                    break;
                case "mms":
                    bd.setMMS(adto);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    return bd;
}
}
```

I tested it with this simple program:

```
public class JsonArrayExampleApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    String json = "{\"accumulators\": [{\"balance\": \"100\",\"name\": \"SMS\",\"units\": \"International SMS\"" +
    "},{\"balance\": \"100\",\"name\": \"VOICE\",\"units\": \"minutes\"},{\"balance\": \"50\",\"name\": \"MMS\"," +
    "\"units\": \"MMS\"}]}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule("MyModule");
    mod.addDeserializer(BaseDTO.class, new CustomDeserializer(BaseDTO.class));
    mapper.registerModule(mod);

    BaseDTO bdto = null;
    try {
        bdto = mapper.readValue(json, BaseDTO.class);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("\n--- JSON to JAVA ---\n" + bdto);
}
}
```

and I got the following output that seems to be ok, because every AccumulatorDTO has been associated to the right property.

```
--- JSON to JAVA ---
BaseDTO [messages=AccumulatorDTO [balance=100, name=SMS, units=International SMS], minutes=AccumulatorDTO [balance=100, name=VOICE, units=minutes], MMS=AccumulatorDTO [balance=50, name=MMS, units=MMS]]
```